# Unit testing Angular 2 service throws error when importing angular modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, angular

I'm actually studying `angular 2` and I m building a simple application in which I have a `MathComponent` and a `MathCustom` calculator.

Here are the two classes :

Component :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MathCustom} from './math.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'math-calcul',
  template: '<h1>Simple math calculator</h1>' +
  '<input type="number" placeholder="a"  [(ngModel)]="a"/>' +
  '<input type="number" placeholder="b"  [(ngModel)]="b"/>' +
  '<button (click)="addition(a,b)">Calculate</button>' +
  ' <br/> = {{result}}',
  providers: [MathCustom]
})
export class MathComponent {
  public result = 0;

  constructor(math: MathCustom) {
    this.math = math;
  }

  addition(a: Number, b: Number) {
    this.result = this.math.add(a, b);
  }
}
```

Service :

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class MathCustom {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Here are the service tests :

```
import {MathCustom} from '../../src/math/math.js';

let service = new MathCustom();

    describe('MathCustom', () => {
      describe('MathCustom#add', () => {

        it('expects 1 + 1 to equals 2', () => {
          expect(service.add(1, 1)).toEqual(2);
        });

        it('expects 2 + 3 to equals 5', () => {
          expect(service.add(2, 3)).toEqual(5);
        });

        it('expects 10 + 10 to equals 20', () => {
          expect(service.add(10, 10)).toEqual(20);
        });
      });
    });
```

**Problem**

My problem is that on my service (MathCustom) class, I have something injected from the `angular 2` node_module :

> import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

and this throws me this error when I try to run my tests :

> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:3000/app/test/angular2/core(…)

Actually, it's normal because my angular2/core is at the root of the project, not inside the test folder.

My project structure :

[image]

#### How can I avoid this import behaviour ?

Comment: You need to tell your test runner (karma, I assume?) where angular modules are located. Take a look at [my configuration](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/0939f5bb00285e82af21), hope it helps...

Comment: Was this issue resolved. I am testing from the browser. and getting this error. It does not seem to be recognizing the .js extension specified in the script tag, I believe.